# Drake Mathematical Program Tutorial

Tags: drake

I am running Drake on Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL2.
I use python3.8.10 and Drake1.2.0.
I tried running the "Mathematical Program Tutorial" obtained from [deepnote](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/%2Fmathematical_program.ipynb) on my PC, but the behavior of the ipopt solver is unnatural and does not give the expected results.

The 1st error is occurred in the section using ipopt solver.
All components of the solution is printed as "nan"

The 2nd error is below about "get_solver_details().status"

```
RuntimeError: The solver_details has not been set yet.
```

I can see both errors in "Demo on manually choosing a solver" in the tutorial.
The result is following

```
SolutionResult.kUnknownError
x* =  [nan nan]
Solver is  IPOPT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2d1b3835c54a> in <module>
     25 print("x* = ", result.GetSolution(x))
     26 print("Solver is ", result.get_solver_id().name())
---> 27 print("Ipopt solver status: ", result.get_solver_details().status,
 28       ", meaning ", result.get_solver_details().ConvertStatusToString())

RuntimeError: The solver_details has not been set yet.
```

Thank you in advance.

---

P.S.
I installed  pydrake for venv by pip commands

```
python3 -m venv env
env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
env/bin/pip install drake
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends \
  libpython3.8 libx11-6 libsm6 libxt6 libglib2.0-0
source env/bin/activate
```

I just download the folder "Tutorial" from [deepnote](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/%2Fmathematical_program.ipynb) and put it under env.

Then, I run it by Jupyter Notebook as

```
jupyter notebook
```

and open env/Tutorials/mathematical_program.ipynb

Comment: I just run the tutorial locally on my PC as `bazel run //tutorials:mathematical_program` and the solver runs fine. Could you talk more about how you run the tutorial locally? Did you clone drake's source code to your PC and do `bazel run //tutorials:mathematical_program`?

Comment: I added how to run the tutorial locally.

Comment: FYI The main problem is the `SolutionResult.kUnknownError` message -- the solver failed to find a solution, for some reason.  The "details have not been set" failure is a direct consequence of that.  We need to figure out why `kUnknownError` is happening.

Comment: Are there something I can to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the pip `drake == 1.2.0` version has a [bug in the IpoptSolver compilation](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17162).

As a work-around, you can use `SnoptSolver` instead, or else use the https://drake.mit.edu/from_binary.html release (unpacking a zipped binary, instead of using pip).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try later(binary) one.

Comment: There is no error in Mathematical Program Tutorial if I use  the binary one `/v1.2.0/drake-20220420-focal.tar.gz`. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `pydrake.solvers.ipopt.IpoptSolver` class (which is a wrapper around the https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/ library) does not run correctly under WSL2, due to using some odd libc API which doesn't work on Windows.  We will need more information to reproduce the problem and try to debug.

Can you state exactly how you installed pydrake (i.e., show us the command lines you used). Was it via pip (https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html) or just via binary (https://drake.mit.edu/from_binary.html)?

Can you state exactly how you ran Jupyter (the command line) to launch the notebook?  Was it `python3 -m pydrake.tutorials` or something else?

Comment: Thanks for updating your main post with more details.  The install steps look correct.  Sorry for your trouble!  I will need to try to reproduce the problem on my own WSL2 before I can offer any good advice.

Comment: I don't think it will help, but can you try running the tutorial using `python3 -m pydrake.tutorials` instead of `jupyter notebook`?  The tutorials are actually already installed as part of pip.

Comment: Thank for your quick responses. I will try to do so. I did not know that the tutorials  are already installed.

Comment: When I try to use `pydrake3 -m pydrake.tutorials`, first I put the token to the jupyter and then index is opened. Next, I select `mathmatical program` and do `Restart & Run All`. Finally same error (i.e. nan solution and `The solver_details has not been set yet.`)  occurred.

Comment: Seems like it's the same result.  Someone will need to test on WSL2 to debug this, since it only seems to happen there.  In the meantime, one possibly work-around would be to use SNOPT instead of IPOPT. You could locally change the tutorial to run that solver instead, and see if that avoids whatever problem IPOPT is having.

Comment: If I change IPOPT to SNOPT, the solution is obtained. However the part to get status made some another error as `AttributeError: 'pydrake.solvers.snopt.SnoptSolverDetails' object has no attribute 'status'`. I think it is normal behavior and simply SNOPT does not have any status.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may not be tied to WSL, but instead pip build (or just binary build). Ran into this on Ubuntu 20.04 (no WSL). Per Drake Slack, filed issue:

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17162